# Software to modify text in a clipboard with hotkey

Tags: windows, plain-text, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

So I need a piece of software that does the following:

1. I have say the text string "ABCDEF" in my clipboard
2. I press a hotkey
3. I have the text string "ABCDEF+GHI" in my clipboard

Now I can paste the modified text of my choosing

Does such a software exist? I need it mostly to output some HTML code that I constantly paste over and over again, but I want it to pre-designate some text that I define.

Basically, an editor that concatenates text strings.

Ideally, it'd run on my computer. Since it can work with hotkeys. The other method would be me to run a Chrome plugin where I paste the input, and get an output.

Comment: If you're on Windows, this sounds like a job for AutoHotKey: https://www.autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created the following [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script

```
^g:: 

send, {ctrl down}c{ctrl up} 
SendInput, <a href="{ctrl down}v{ctrl up}"><img src="{ctrl down}v{ctrl up}" title="source: imgur.com" /></a> return
```

With it, I can highlight a URL and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and I get a new output text:

[image: Animation]

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the formatting possibilities and your answers will be even better.